# Generate key from array

Tags: c#

What do you think about quality of code in this method?

It should:

- Generate new key based on keys in array
- The key should start with "TG"
- Code should find the max number in array keys with "TG-" and increment this number
- It should have 7 digits
- No need to check what if there is a key TG9999999, and what if array is empty or doesn't have keys "TG-"

```
private static string[] allKeys = new string[]
{
    "TG0000006",
    "TG0000026",
    "TG0000086",
    "TG0000796",
    "TG0023106",
    "LG0004406",
    "MS0000796",
    "TT0023106",
    "LK0004406",
};

static string GenerateKey()
{
    var keys = allKeys.Where(k => k.StartsWith("TG"));
    List<int> nums = new List<int>();
    foreach (var key in keys.Select(str => Regex.Match(str, @"\d+").Value))
    {
        int num;
        if (int.TryParse(key, out num))
            nums.Add(num);
    }
    string newNum = (nums.Max() + 1).ToString();
    return "TG" + new string('0', 7 - newNum.Length) + newNum;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

- If you want only the numbers `0..9` to be matched by the `Regex` and you don't care about for instance some Eastern Arabic numerals like `´٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩`, then you should use an expression like `[0-9]+`.
- because by using either the `d+` or `[0-9]+` expression you already made sure that the `var key` is a number. Because this number has at the maximum 7 digits, you can simply call `Parse()` instead of `TryParse()` which eleminates the usage of the `int num`.
- please add always braces `{}` although they might be optional. This will make your code less error prone.
- the return statement

  > ```
  > return "TG" + new string('0', 7 - newNum.Length) + newNum;
  > ```

  can be simplified by using the `PadLeft()` method like so

  ```
  return "TG" +  newNum.PadLeft(7,'0');
  ```
- personally I would just have a `if` clase for checking the highest number instead of the `List<int>` together with the call to `Max()`.

Putting this all together leads to

```
static string GenerateKey()
{
    int max = int.MinValue;
    var keys = allKeys.Where(k => k.StartsWith("TG"));
    foreach (var key in keys.Select(str => Regex.Match(str, @"[0-9]+").Value))
    {
        int num = int.Parse(key);
        if (num > max)
        {
            max = num;
        }
    }

    return "TG" + (max + 1).ToString().PadLeft(7, '0');
}
```